# Laravel 4.2 Auth Dependency Injection

Tags: laravel-4

i'm trying to inject the Auth into a dedicated class for authentication http://laravel.io/bin/8e3z7 but i'm getting this error "Class auth does not exist ".
can anyone check the code in the provided link and tell me what i'm missing here? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems fine apart the line:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager as Auth;
```

You have to use Guard instead

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Guard as Auth;
```

and everything should be fine :)

As you can see in the Laravel docs http://laravel.com/docs/facades#facade-class-reference it returns the Auth instance.